# How to fix hex characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the content of the image jpg file as hex. However, characters with 0 are not being displayed correctly. For example lets say we have C0 it only shows C.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("steg.jpg", "r");
    int z = 0;
    unsigned char out;
    while(z!=-1){
        
        z=fscanf(fp,"%c", &out);
        if(z!=-1){
            printf("%X ", out);
        }else{
            break;
        }
        
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Simple answer: `%02X`.

Comment: The `scanf()` function is intended to be used with text, but `.jpg` files are binary. I suggest you read each byte with `fgetc()`, for example `int ch = fgetc(fp)`.

Comment: You should use `EOF` instead of magic number `-1`.

Comment: when the file reaches the end fscanf will start repeating the last character or string which will result in a -1 value which is similar to EOF. But I can say that using EOF is better. Thank you.  @Lundin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getc` each byte and print it

```
    int z = 0;
    unsigned char out;
    while((z = getc(fp)) != -1){
        printf("%02X ", z);
    }
```

You'll want to add a counter and print newlines every so many characters.